# Create custom frame for image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I have a list of cards. These cards contain images. So I have to create a custom frame for an image with bottom info block.

It must be customizable cause I'm using it diff version few times.

I've tried to create a custom view group with ImageView, one TextView and one Path with corner radius, but it's hard because I can't draw TextView on top of the path which is on top of the ImageView.

```
 override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {

    imageView.layout(
        left,
        top,
        right,
        bottom - 50
    )

    textView.layout(
        500, 700,
        600,
        800
    )
}

override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas)
    canvas!!.drawPath(mBottomShape, mBottomShapePaint)
}

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)

    val bottom = viewHeight - 50

    mBottomShape.moveTo(viewWidth * 0.47F, bottom.toFloat() * 1.01f)
    mBottomShape.lineTo(viewWidth * 0.53F, bottom * 0.99F)
    mBottomShape.lineTo(viewWidth * 0.55F, bottom * 0.93F)
    mBottomShape.lineTo(viewWidth * 0.7F, bottom * 0.93F)
    mBottomShape.lineTo(viewWidth * 0.72F, bottom * 0.99F)
    mBottomShape.lineTo(viewWidth * 0.78F, bottom.toFloat() * 1.01f)

    mBottomShape.close()

    setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight)
}
```

What i need to achieve :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can draw `TextView` on top, just override `onDraw()` method and last items that you are drawing going to be on top

Comment: But how i know texview draws by textview.layout(l,t,r,b). cause its viewgroup

Comment: In general I would make custom ImageView with overriding drawing bottom part where you need to leave gap, then would add TextView with background using Constraint layout and thats it

Comment: how would u implement this curved white background ?

Comment: By extending ImageView  and customizing shape of it and not drawing where curved white background should be

Comment: u mean that u will track position of textview ?

Comment: No, when have custom image view with cropped curved corner, you can simply add textview on top and thats it

Comment: U said that u would use contraintlayout for adding textview, and shape imageview by creating custom view. I cant understand how u will know positions of this two elements. Textview can be more wider. So textview position cant be hardcoded.

Comment: Using ConstraintLayout